# Java - charAt(), equalsIgnoreCase, if statement testing?

Tags: java, if-statement, input, equals, charat

What I want is no matter what the user inputs, if the first letter of their input is either a 'y' or 'n' regardless of case, it will print "game start".

I've tried equalsIgnoreCase() with the "letter" variable but it gives the error:  char cannot be dereferenced.  Any recommendations will be really appreciated on this!  Thanks!

```
Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);

System.out.println("Do you want to continue?");

String wesker = input.nextLine();
char letter = wesker.charAt(0);

 if(letter == 'y' || letter == 'p'){
     System.out.println("Game start");
 } else {
     System.out.println("Game over");
 }
```

Comment: Is that supposed to be a `'p'` or a `'n'`?

Comment: Your code checks for `y` and `p`.. BTW why not just check for `Y`, `N` ,`y` and `N`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

equalsIgnoreCase can be used only by Strings. For your case, if you want to use that method, you can do this:

```
Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
String wesker = input.nextLine();
String letter = wesker.substring(0,1);

if(letter.equalsIgnoreCase("y") || letter.equalsIgnoreCase("n")){
    System.out.println("Game start");
} else {
    System.out.println("Game over");
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Try use `Character#toLowercase()`:

```
if (Character.toLowerCase(letter) == 'y' || Character.toLowerCase(letter) == 'n') {
```

or

```
if (Character.toUpperCase(letter) == 'Y' || Character.toUpperCase(letter) == 'N') {
```

or simply

```
if( letter == 'y' || letter == 'Y' || letter == 'n' || letter == 'N' )
```

Answer (score 2):

Just check against both cases:

```
if( letter == 'y' || letter == 'Y' || letter == 'p' || letter == 'P' )
```

Answer (score 0):

You could pre-build a set of acceptable characters.

```
Set<Character> yes = new HashSet<>(Arrays.asList('y','Y','p','P'));

public void test() {
    char letter = 'c';
    if ( yes.contains(letter)) {

    }
}
```

Comment: I guess with a bit more thinking, we can find an even more resource consuming solution…

Comment: @Holger - Working on that ... :)

Comment: If you want to test against a pre-built a set of acceptable characters, you may consider `"yYnN".indexOf(letter)!=-1`. For such a small set, hashing is not faster than a linear search.

Comment: @Holger - I was thinking of using a custom comparator too - but decided that was a little too OTT. Good point on the `indexOf`.